# Trouble with toggling visibility of a link_to in a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

It's been a very long time since I've touched anything to do with Javascript or Coffeescript, still pretty new to RoR and I'm having some trouble getting an eventlistener to work.

Currently tags on my app are displayed with an 'x' that functions as a delete link. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: [image]

(in case my photo isn't loading) I want the displayed tag to show the name, and when hovered over, I'd like the x to be visible.

ERB:

```
<div class="desktop-only">
  <% contact.tags.last(2).each do |t| %>
    <span class="badge badge-color" id="tag-id-<%=t.id %>-<%=contact.id%>-d"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-html="true"
        data-placement="top" 
        title="<%= t.name%>">
      <div class='truncate'><%= t.name %></div>
      <%= link_to 'x', remove_tag_contact_path(contact, t), remote: true, class: 'tag-remove', id:'tag-remove', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete the tag?' } %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
  <% if contact.tags.count > 2 %>
    <span class="badge badge-light" id="count-<%= contact.id %>-d">+<%= contact.tags.count-2 %></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

.coffee:

```
toggle_tag = ->
    tag_remove = document.getElementById('tag-remove')
    display = ->
        tag_remove.style.visibility = 'visible'
    hide = ->
        tag_remove.style.visibility = 'none'
    tag_remove.addEventListener 'mouseover', display
    tag_remove.addEventListener 'mouseout', hide

window.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', toggle_tag
```

Currently the tags aren't changing on mouseover, and I cannot figure out why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: my guess would be that you need to query by class instead of id so that you select every tag, and then on each tag you add an event listener. Also, you probably want to use `display: none` instead of `visibility`, since "invisible" elements still take up space on the page. Or even remove the element entirely, instead of hiding it. Also, a different approach would be to just use CSS, with `.tag-remove:hover` and `.tag-remove:not(:hover)`

Comment: I don't know coffee but why not just css ? `.tag-remove{display: none;} .truncate:hover+a.tag-remove {display: inline-block;}` or something like that..